Which 'laws of indices' hold for complex bases and real powers?
Specifically, I would like to know whether:
$$z^a z^b = z^{a+b}$$
$$(zw)^a = z^a w^a$$
$$(z^a)^b = z^{ab}$$
hold true for any and all $z,w \in \Bbb{C}$ and  $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$?
Also, I'd be interested to see any others that hold.

You should ask the question for $z,w\in \mathbb{C}\setminus 0$ as there should be no meaning for $z^{-1}$ when $z=0$.

If $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ then all three properties hold, otherwise, in general, only the first one does.
By the definition of complex exponential, $$z^az^b=e^{a\operatorname{Log}(z)}e^{b\operatorname{Log}(z)}=e^{(a+b)\operatorname{Log}(z)}=z^{a+b}$$
where the second equality is justified because of the properties of the exponential.
As for the second and third properties, consider the $[-\pi,\pi)$ branch of the logarithm. Then,$$(i\cdot i)^{1/2}=(-1)^{1/2}=e^{\operatorname{Log}(-1)/2}=e^{-i\pi/2}=-i\neq i=e^{i\pi/4}e^{i\pi/4}=e^{\operatorname{Log}(i)/2}e^{\operatorname{Log}(i)/2}=i^{1/2}i^{1/2}$$
and $$(i^2)^{1/2}=(-1)^{1/2}=-i\neq i= i^{2\cdot 1/2}$$

What about $(z^{-1})^{-1}=z$ when $z=0$?

@jjagmath We are obviously talking about non-zero bases here.

The three rules cannot hold even for $z,w\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$. If all three rules hold,

$z^az^b=z^{a+b}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$

$(zw)^a=z^aw^a$ for all $z,w\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ and $a\in \mathbb{Q}$

$(z^a)^b=z^{ab}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$


If you also stipulate that

$z^1=z$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$

then one obtains a contradiction. First, by 2,

$1^a=1$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Q}$

Therefore
\begin{align*}
1&=1^\frac{1}{2} & (5)\\
&=((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{2} & \\
&=(-1)^1 & (3)\\
&=-1 & (4)
\end{align*}
Replacing $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ with $\mathbb{C}\setminus 0$ does not change anything.

At a high level, we can explain the problem. Notice that the conditions 1-4 actually state that the abelian group $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ under $\times$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. This is incompatible with the existence of torsion elements. In our case, $-1$ is torsion as $(-1)^2=1$. The problem does actually go away if we restrict to positive reals for the base of the exponent.

If you take the principal branch of the logarithm, with a discontinuity at the non-positive reals, and define $z^w:=\exp(w\log z)$, then properties 1, 4, and 5 hold.

The existing answers address it from one perspective, for which only the first rule holds. However, from a different perspective, all of them hold.
The complication arises because, strictly speaking, $a^b$ is not uniquely defined for a given $a$ unless $b$ is an integer. For all non-integer values of $b$, we are forced to consider the so-called "principal value" if we want an unique value.
As noted by Joshua Tilley, you have the situation of $1^{1/2}$, which can be equal to either $1$ or $-1$. If you consider, say, $1^\pi$, then there are a countably infinite number of possible values, all on the unit circle on the complex plane.
You can consider this to arise because any value in the complex plane could be represented, in polar coordinates, as $re^{i\theta}=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$... but increasing $\theta$ by a multiple of $2\pi$ will produce the same complex value. And so, when you raise to a power, you can think of it as raising any of these representations to that power.
If you view it from this perspective, then all of the index laws work... but only if you specify the $w$ and $z$ values in polar coordinates, with $\theta$ being permitted to be any real number (not just between $0$ and $2\pi$). Note that the $r$ in the polar representation is real, and thus the usual index laws apply.
So to return to $1^{1/2}$, we have $1 = e^{i2n\pi}$, where $n$ is an integer. And then when we take the power, we have $1^{1/2} = e^{in\pi}$, which is $1$ when $n$ is even and $-1$ when $n$ is odd.

There is a common misconception that these identities completely die on the complex plane. While they don't hold in general, these identities do hold for any exponential spiral.
Consider the spiral in the complex plane generated by $c^t$ where $c$ is a complex number of your choice and $t$ is a real number parameter of your choice that is varied from $(-\infty, \infty)$.
For ANY two $u,v$ on this spiral and $a,b$ in $\mathbb{R}$  it is always the case that $u^a u^b = u^{a+b}, (u^{a})^{b} = u^{ab}, (uv)^{a} = u^av^a$
To get better a grip on this let us represent $c = re^{iq}$ in polar coordinates. Then the parametric graph of $(\cos(qt)r^t, \sin(qt)r^{-t})$ represents an exponential spiral where these laws hold.
I made a link on desmos so you can play with these spirals and get a better idea of how they work
To fit this into ideas you are familiar with $q=0$ and $r > 0$ recovers back the original positive real number line where we are familiar with these identities holding.
It's worth pointing out that these spirals ALSO are places where $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$ is well defined and $\ln(a^b) = b\ln(a)$ is recovered as well.
Instead of using the "principal branch cut of the logarithm" (which is fine for the positive reals) you want to cut your logarithm in such a way that a spiral of your choice remains on the cut. Then, for THAT spiral, you can still use the logarithm in the naive way.

When you say that all three rules hold `'on a spiral' that is not correct. Only the first rule can be formulated using only one 'spiral' since the other two rules use more than one base simultaneously.

The bases $u,v$ can come from the same spiral.
